How to buy residential realty, without conveying purchase money to any lawyer’s trust account?
What are safer ways to pay the purchase money to the vendor, without relying on any lawyer’s "trust" account, undertakings, or faith?
Solely for hiring a real estate lawyer for conveyancing, I am willing to pay a legal retainer and fees to their trust account. But I would hate to pay millions in PURCHASE CAPITAL to any lawyer’s trust account, because suspended lawyers Nicholas Cartel’s and Singa Bui’s embezzlements make me distrust lawyers.

Indeed, most real estate transactions these days rely in some way on lawyer's undertakings and good faith.
A couple of decades ago, the typical process for closing a home sale in Ontario involved the buyer providing two certified cheques — one made out to the seller's bank for the remaining mortgage amount on the home, and another to the seller for the balance of the purchase price. That way, only the company holding the mortgage on a home could cash the first cheque and get that money.
Nowadays, buyers' lawyers usually just wire the money, relying on the promise of the seller's lawyer to pay off the mortgage from those funds. This introduces a risk that a rogue solicitor on either end of the deal might simply pinch the funds.
"Wire transfer has become a norm and that is very risky, because in spite of the fact that the lawyers are giving undertakings, it may or may not happen," said Balvinder Kumar, a veteran real estate lawyer in Mississauga, Ont.

See Ingarra v. Cartel & Bui LLP, et al., 2024 ONSC 6228 (CanLII), [19]:

[19] Based on the deemed admissions I find that Ms. Bui breached her fiduciary duty to the plaintiffs. Instead of paying the funds to the plaintiffs in accordance with her retainer, she misappropriated the funds for her own use. I am satisfied that Ms. Bui acted in a manner that was callous, high-handed and reprehensible. Her conduct is particularly egregious because at the time, she was a licenced lawyer and officer of the court.


I’m voting to close this question because it is not about a law, it should probably be at money@se

As a side note: In Germany, trust accounts for buying real estate fell out of use long ago. Instead you sign a contract, "block" the real estate in the land register, pay the money, and then get the real estate.

Your fear is greatly exaggerated. While all custodians of funds pose risks, lawyers are close to as safe as it gets. This said, there are alternatives, in theory at least, although not all of the options would be possible without resistance for deviating from commercial norms in the market in question.
There are professional escrow companies that hold funds. You could also just present a cashier's check at closing (with the risk that you'd be mugged en route to closing or lose it). Sometimes real estate brokers will hold escrowed funds as well. Or, you could wire funds directly to the seller, with the deed held in escrow by an attorney, rather than the money, since it is hard to abscond with real estate.
You could also bring a duffle bag full of cash to a pre-arranged place in a dark alley near a bunch of warehouses. This is the preferred method of exchanging large sums of cash in some industries.

please, can you expand n your second paragraph? And delete the first and last sarcastic paragraphs? This fear is well founded, not "greatly exaggerated". Many other Ontario lawyers defrauded home buyers - see Ping-Teng Tan, Shalid Malik.

@user16249 It is not well-founded because other options are worse.

@user16249 It is not well-founded because you're cherry-picking those cases amongst literally millions of other interactions with lawyers. You might also get run over by a drunk driver when you leave your house - you'll find many more examples of that than you will lawyers stealing from clients - but never leaving your house for fear of drunk drivers would not be well founded.

Re: bag full of cash - in the US you should not, as I understand any police office can confiscate cash from you on the ground they reasonably believed it was not for a legit case, and then it would be your responsibility to prove otherwise.

@Mykola in "some industries" losing money to the police is an accepted risk.

@Graham if it has happen already you might want to avoid it as the amount in question is not just a lot, for some it is impossible to pay it back - and rent at the same time. I believe if trust was undermined, it is unreasonable to mock a person who worries it might happen to them, or just say to them "oh, it only happen to very few, it will be fine!" We should learn from other's mistakes - and if it is possible to avoid the scenario - why shouldn't you? I personally find banks are much more trust-able in this cases, and layers are much less - as they are individuals with their problems.

@Mykola I'm not mocking - this was an entirely fair and reasonable analogy.  If the OP had had this happen to them personally, perhaps it would be reasonable for them to be excessively cautious.  Since the OP has no personal experience of this (I assume; I expect the question would have said if they had), but has merely read about it and from that has adopted an unfounded prejudice against hundreds of thousands of professional people, it would be strange to be complicit in supporting such an irrational belief.

If you read the Law Society of Upper Canada discipline notes, there are two items that occur very frequently every issue: Failing to file paperwork, and Messing with trust funds.

@Graham If such happen to me - I would not know how I would live as I would need to pay back the mortgage stolen by the solicitor, and pay for the rent. And when/if I finally pay it all back - I don't think I will be capable to take another mortgage as I will be too old to work. With this much money it is unreasonable for most people to expect to have any experience, as many don't buy more than 2-3 homes per their life. And I do not find it strange to not trust "professional people" - as why would I? Banks are more regulated - and this much money is not that much for them to loose the license.

@Mykola The Northern Rock bank failed in the UK. Other banks have failed all over the world. And if someone happens to get your account details, banks have a famous track record at refusing to give you any money back. If you think banks are regulated enough that you won't lose your money, you don't know enough about banks! But they're still safer to keep your money than not using them. And companies in the UK at least all have multi-million-pound indemnity insurance, precisely so that if something like this happens, clients have some kind of recourse.

@user16249 “3” is not “many”, it is more accurately “few”.

Being a small statistical risk TO SOCIETY is different than being catastrophic to an individual (at least in the near term)  until the responsible professional society makes good on their members deviation from their professional norms. That statistical social risk is the reason for insurance but yet built on that is the reinsurance industry.

Generally when dealing with a multi-step transaction with large amounts of money involved you'd need some trust in the intermediaries. Lawyers would probably be a better option since in case of embezzlement they have a whole lot to lose compared to an anonymous escrow company. However there's always a risk, which is why all these providers should also carry insurance.
Like with any other service provider, you can ask them to present a certificate of insurance (COI) and confirm with the insurer its authenticity and applicability to the risk.
Examples of risks:

Cash - unreasonable for such a large amount, can be lost, stolen, robbed, and the seller may take the cash and not sign off the title.
Wiring directly to the seller - similarly, they may not sign off the title to you after receiving the money.
Certified checks - can be forged and it takes time to verify authenticity (weeks, or even longer).
Escrow companies - unless regulated and insured, the risk of embezzlement and misuse of funds is actually higher than with lawyers. In the US in some states these are very strictly regulated and are usually being used for this process, in others you'll find lawyers doing that.
Lawyer trust accounts - strictly regulated and the lawyer is personally liable with the risk of losing their livelihood and freedom if caught mishandling something.

In the end of the day sellers want assurance that they're being paid and buyers want assurance that they're getting what they're paying for, and it cannot be done without one doing something before the other. So a trusted intermediary is a necessary step in a transaction of this type.

"Can the home buyer buy fraudulent lawyer insurance?" It's tricky. Most lawyers carry malpractice insurance. If the lawyer is part of a law firm and the firm provides the insurance, malpractice insurance will probably cover the loss. But if the lawyer is a sole practitioner, the fraud will be an intentional act of the insured and probably won't be covered. Where I practice, in Colorado, there is a state fund, paid for with the interest on lawyer's trust accounts, that covers trust account fraud losses, but I don't know if there is something similar in Canada.

If you have a contract which says the ownership title belongs to you as soon as the money is wired to a certain bank account, what can go wrong? Assuming you’ve checked the identity of the seller and checked in the land title register that they are really the owner.

@Michael of course, silly me, there were never any contract defaults in the universe. What can go wrong? You're out of tons of money and now need to spend more on litigation.

@littleadv: I don’t know anything about law, but if for some reason the owner refuses to hand over the title, shouldn’t it be pretty straightforward to sue? You (or rather your bank) can prove you’ve wired the money, so even if the owner says they’ve never signed the contract or never received the money you have a pretty strong case, no?

@Michael to sue? yeah, pretty straightforward. But you've clearly never been involved in any litigation. Even the most straigtforward case can take months. It took me several months and several hundreds of dollars to take myself off of a lawsuit I was put on by mistake (wrong person with the same name, happens a lot apparently). In the meantime you're out of money, and who knows how the lawsuit will resolve and when.
